# Remotely identify a memory leak in an application used by a customer

Tags: java, memory-leaks

A customer is complaining that he's experiencing a memory leak in our Java application.

Despite all my efforts to reproduce his environment, configuration and usage, I wasn't able to reproduce, and thus identify, the leak.

I'd want to go down another path... Instead of trying to replicate it, maybe I could ask him to generate *some view* of his heap that would allow me to identify the leak.

Being run by the customer who would send it to me, there are some requirements on this:

1. Should not contain confidential info
2. Should be small enough that it can be sent through the internet
3. Should be generated by an easily available tool (would be best if it was in the Java distribution)

A complete heap dump is impossible because of 1. and 2.

Most of all, it should allow me to find the leak. So it should at least show the retained heap size for objects of each class (size of itself + everything it keeps a reference to).
`jmap -histo` is definitely not good enough.

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         14156      577318512  [B
   2:          9196       47439696  [I
   3:         83396        9809992  [C
```

Is something like that useful at all? I don't think so.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a tool that extracts the information you need from a full heap dump and get the customer to run it. The customer could then review the resultant report for confidential information prior to sending it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the customer allowed to do a memory dump himself without sending it to you?

If that is possible, the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) has a really easy to use wizard which will generate a leak suspect report. The report itself is very small.

Comment: I was already investigating this solution when you posted it, and this is the one I'm ending up with for now. MAT can even generate this report in a scriptable way with the included [ParseHeapDump.sh](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_run_on_64bit_VM_while_the_native_SWT_are_32bit). I used this feature to write a script that automatically gets the PID of our application, dumps the heap with jmap and runs MAT. I've asked the customer to run it and send me the report... Let's now hope it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a bit more about you and your customers it is hard to comment but in my experience a customer telling me we have a memory leak (especially in Java) just means "customer's system has some problem that may or may not be related to our app"

I'd start by something as simple a finding out why he thinks your app has a leak (i.e. ps or task manager output showing process sizes)

Comment: I've already established that. We almost certainly do have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the client to run [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) and somehow connect remotely to the web server that it starts up.

Answer (score -1):

I would take a heap dump and analyse it with YourKit. (I found jhat too difficult with large applications)